# Adding a record to the database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace lab1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); //holding place in memory
    SqlDataAdapter daParent = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlDataAdapter daChild = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=user-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=dede;Integrated Security=TRUE");

    BindingSource ParentBS = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource ChildBS = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand slctParent = new SqlCommand("select * from Developerss", cs); //select statement
        daParent.SelectCommand = slctParent; // attaching sql command into the select command property of the data adapter Parent
        daParent.Fill(ds, "Developerss"); //fullfilling the data set, calling the table Parent

        SqlCommand slctChild = new SqlCommand("select * from Games", cs);
        daParent.SelectCommand = slctChild; 
        daParent.Fill(ds,"Games");

        dgParent.DataSource = ds.Tables["Developerss"];
        dgChild.DataSource = ds.Tables["Games"];
        dgParent.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dgChild.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;//click anywhere in the table we have the whole row selected

        ParentBS.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ChildBS.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];

        textId.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text",ChildBS,"game_id"));
        textName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ChildBS, "game_name"));
        textPlatform.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ChildBS, "game_platform"));
        textDeveloperId.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ParentBS, "d_id"));


    }

    private void dgParent_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ds.Tables["Games"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "developer_id = " + dgParent.CurrentRow.Cells["d_id"].Value;
        //whenever the selection change on the dgparent use the value of the current row that we're on
        dgChild.DataSource = ds.Tables["Games"];
    }

    private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        daChild.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into Games values @id, @name, @platform, @developerId", cs);
        daChild.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textId.Text;
        daChild.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textName.Text;
        daChild.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@platform", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textPlatform.Text;
        daChild.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@developerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[ParentBS.Position][0];

        cs.Open();
        daChild.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cs.Close();

    }
```

Hello there!

I have a problem with the `insert` command. I get the following error :

> Incorrect syntax near 'game_id'.

Yes the column exists in the database. I get the same error for my update function but I have not posted it here since i believe it must come from the same error source. I have 2 data grids, one is parent, the other child. Basically i want to add new records in the child table.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Take a look into Entity Framework. It can generate all this boilerplate code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `INSERT` syntax is totally wrong - you should use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Games(Co1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (@id, @name, @platform, @developerId)
```

First of all: I recommend to **always** explicitly specify the **list of columns** you want to insert into.

And secondly: the `VALUES` need to have **parenthesis** around the list of values it will insert.

And for a next time - **please** look up the **excellent, freely available** SQL Server documentation first! Totally basic stuff like this can be **easily** found online - e.g. the details about the `INSERT` syntax [can be found here on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

That documentation is very thorough, it shows all the details, all the options, all the various ways of using it, and it has plenty of sample code, too - **please USE that documentation** before asking such basic questions here (using documentation and looking up stuff is **part of being** a developer, after all!)  - thank you.